# How Coalesce function deals with datatype

Tags: mysql, amazon-redshift, coalesce

I am new to COALESCE function in REDSHIFT. I ran below four queries in mysql and Redshift.

1st and 2nd query executed as expected in both mysql and redshift. But for 3rd and 4th query I am getting two different results in mysql and Redshift. How does this behave?

1. `select COALESCE(null,null,1)` -> `1`
2. `select COALESCE(null,null,'John')` -> `1`
3. `select COALESCE(null,null,1,'John')` -> (Redshift : `error` , mysql:`1`)
4. `select COALESCE(null,null,'John',1)`    -> (Redshift: `error`, mysql:`John`)

Also this query should give error in mysql but it has succeeded
Any help is appreciated

Comment: _"this query should give error in mysql but it has succeeded"_ ? MySQL COALESCE() Function returns the first non-null value in a list. Your #3 & #4 results for MySQL are correct

Comment: Moreover, in MySQL `select COALESCE(null,null,1,'John') UNION ALL select COALESCE(null,null,'John',1)` is correct too!

Answer (score 1):

[Amazon Redshift Database Developer Guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_NVL_function.html) claims:

> An NVL expression is identical to a COALESCE expression. NVL and
>   COALESCE are synonyms.
>
> **Syntax**
>
> ```
> NVL | COALESCE ( expression, expression, ... )
> ```
>
> An NVL or COALESCE expression returns the value of the first expression
>   in the list that is not null. If all expressions are null, the result
>   is null. **When a non-null value is found, the remaining expressions in
>   the list are not evaluated.**
>
> This type of expression is useful when you want to return a backup
>   value for something when the preferred value is missing or null. For
>   example, a query might return one of three phone numbers (cell, home,
>   or work, in that order), whichever is found first in the table (not
>   null).

If you obtain the error this may mean that the returned value datatype do not match the datatype of recordset field or any another structure which must accept the returned value.

PS. Will you show error messages?

Comment: select coalesce(null,null,1,'John')     query give this error : SQL Exception:ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer: "John"

Comment: @SRG Either there is an error in the documentation or there is some query pre-processing step which performs datatype check and generates the error (it may be both on the SQL server side but not described in documentation, and on the client side or in some intermediate service). I'd recommend to use explicit CAST into the most compatible datatype (string type in shown case) for each value. But MySQL does NOT perform such pre-check.

Answer (score 0):

Though it is not written in the documentation, but coalesce works on the compatible data types. Integer and varchar cannot be compared.

The error becomes more evident when you provide column name instead of hard-code values. Try executing this:

```
select coalesce(integer_column, varchar_column) from a_table;
```

You would get an error saying something like this:

> coalesce types integer and varchar cannot be matched.